# Swap image on hover inside sprite

Tags: jquery, css

I have a sprite that I use to display a few images. I am trying to swap the sprite image on hover using just CSS.

```
.sprE {
background-color: transparent;
background-image: url(/i/fW.png);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
height: 30px;
width: 30px
}
.sprE:hover {
background-image: url(/i/fC.png);
cursor: pointer
}
.comply {
background-position: 0 0
}

<span class="sprE comply"></span>
```

It works fine in FireFox but not in IE... I'm sure I could get it to work with a bit of jQuery but before I go that way i thought I'd explore all CSS options.

Comment: What version of IE do you need to support?

Comment: Doc type related? http://www.bernzilla.com/item.php?id=762

Comment: Hmm... it could be the doctype. My current document has <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"> I'll try the strict one.

Comment: This should work just fine.  See http://jsfiddle.net/kDDcn/  works fine for me in IE. 
What version are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it was DOCTYPE related. I changed it to strict and it worked.